# How to get the hyper parameters more easily?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameters

Many models in Machine Learning include hyper parameters. What is the best practice to find those hyper parameters using hold out data? Or what is your way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Grid search and manual search are the most widely use techniques for optimizing hyper-parameters of machine learning algorithms. However, a recent paper published by **James Bergstra** and **Yoshua Bengio** argued that random search is better than grid and manual search for hyper-parameter optimization. For more information about random ( grid and manual ) search  please look at their paper:

[**Random Search for Hyper-Parameter Optimization**](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/bergstra12a/bergstra12a.pdf&ei=BhCWUP_eE8zJrAeXwIHABA&usg=AFQjCNF1gXNq2P-jExfSFEJO0T4pKuVF0A&sig2=3tea-zmw9NrOtxEO210a8g&cad=rja)

Recently, I submitted ( and accepted ) a paper for the [Pattern Recognition Letters](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/pattern-recognition-letters/) Journal. For that paper I used the random search technique.

Comment: hi @Upul thanks for answer, I am realy glad to see that this question is in some sense interesting for researchers.